# Getting strange accuracy numbers when running RNN-LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

So, I am using this code: https://github.com/2wavetech/Time-Series-Analysis-and-Prediction and more specifically the code from the paragraph: "LSTM Network for Regression".

I use my own dataset but the rationale is the same. When I run the code and, after google search, I change this line of code:

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

with this:

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I get accuracy like this:

```
...accuracy: 1.9380e-04
...accuracy: 2.9070e-04
```

I changed it one more time with this line of code:

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=[tensorflow.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])
```

and I got something like this:

```
...accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

So after searching on stackoverflow, I followed this approach and make learning rate for adam equal to 0.0001: [Strange validation loss and accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878325/strange-validation-loss-and-accuracy)
and for 10 epochs I get the following:

```
Epoch 1/10
... - 7s - loss: 0.0524 - accuracy: 1.9380e-04
Epoch 2/10
... - 6s - loss: 0.0489 - accuracy: 1.9380e-04
Epoch 3/10
... - 6s - loss: 0.0446 - accuracy: 1.9380e-04
Epoch 4/10
... - 6s - loss: 0.0440 - accuracy: 1.9380e-04
Epoch 5/10
... - 6s - loss: 0.0439 - accuracy: 2.9070e-04
Epoch 6/10
... - 7s - loss: 0.0436 - accuracy: 2.9070e-04
Epoch 7/10
... - 6s - loss: 0.0434 - accuracy: 1.9380e-04
Epoch 8/10
... - 6s - loss: 0.0432 - accuracy: 2.9070e-04
Epoch 9/10
... - 6s - loss: 0.0432 - accuracy: 2.9070e-04
Epoch 10/10
... - 6s - loss: 0.0431 - accuracy: 1.9380e-04
```

And the

```
Train Score: 9.89 RMSE
Test Score: 8.93 RMSE
```

The graphs are ok I get very small error... Obviously the accuracy is wrong here and the loss is very-very small from the 1st epoch! How can I fix this?

Comment: Accuracy is not a valid metric in regression.

Comment: So only RMSE Train, RMSE test?

Comment: You can choose a regression metric, accuracy is for classification problems.

Comment: Are the loss values, depicted on my first post, normal? I mean, how can I identify something wrong such as overfitting?

Comment: If the difference between loss values are high(train >> test), then it means you are overfitting. Your loss values seem *reasonable*

Comment: The loss in this model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam') is the testing loss right? I cannot understand from the tutorial what the write...

Comment: That loss will be used to optimize the model in training. When evaluating model will return the testing loss (model.evaluate(test set)). You can also try Huber loss.